# how to exclude parent pages from get_pages loop Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, web

I want to display all pages in a one page design.

Now i have this code to do that:

```
<?php 
        $pages = get_pages($args);
        //start loop
        foreach ($pages as $page_data) {
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
            $title = $page_data->post_title;
            $slug = $page_data->post_name;
        ?>
        <!-- Content section -->
        <div class="section" id="<?php echo "$slug" ?>">
            <a name="<?php echo "$slug" ?>"></a>
            <h2><?php echo "$title" ?></h2>
            <?php echo "$content" ?>

        </div>
        <!-- END Content section -->
        <?php } ?>
```

But now it show's also the empty parent pages. How can i exclude them? i found this on a website:

```
if($page->post_parent != 2){
```

But when I insert that into my code i only see the home section.

Is there also a way to apply different templates to the different pages? i know how it is normally done but with a one page website it is difficult.

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing "empty pages" mean they don't have any content inside them.

Try to check if `$content` has anything inside of it, if not, don't display that page.

Put this inside your foreach statement right after `$slug = $page_data->post_name;` and before `?>`

```
if($content == ""){
 continue;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. one step closer to what i want :)